# How to structure multi select queries ERROR: relation "rxg" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Am trying to perform a query on my table(ais):
so this is detailed approach:

limit the search by first recovering : select all ids for points with in a distance of 200km, 
   - then select ids where distance between two points is 300 and received_c is the same
- return those ids,  grouped by _id

```
SELECT rxg._id 
FROM (
      SELECT *  FROM ais 
      WHERE ST_DWithin(geography(point), 
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-95.0217,29.6111), 4326)::geography, 
      200000)
) 
AS rxg, rxg AS b
WHERE ST_DWITHIN (rxg.point, b.point, 300) 
AND rxg._id != b._id
AND rxg.received_c = b.received_c
GROUP BY _id
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think you are having is that you are trying to use a single subquery twice, but you can't do that.  Instead, try using a common table expression (CTE) here, which will inline the code for that subquery twice:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ais 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(geography(point), 
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-95.0217,29.6111), 4326)::geography, 
        200000)
)

SELECT rxg._id
FROM cte rxg
INNER JOIN cte b
    ON rxg._id != b._id AND
       rxg.received_c = b.received_c
WHERE ST_DWITHIN (rxg.point, b.point, 300)
GROUP BY rxg._id;
```

Note also that I replaced your old school implicit join with an implicit inner join.  This is the preferred way of joining tables since the ANSI-92 standard.

Comment: I mean absolutely short and precise for a novice, thank you

Comment: The thing that is still bothering me, is that i have duplicate _ids given we explicitly said  `rxg._id != b._id`

Comment: I don't see how this is possible.  You should edit your question and provide sample data if you still need more help.  The answer I gave solves the immediate problem you asked about.